# How to display Firebase data in HTML [object Object] currently displaying

Tags: javascript, html, database, object, firebase

I've set up the Javascript below to display all the objects in my Firebase database. But when I display it on my webpage it only returns [object Object]. What am I missing?

```
 events.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var eventkey = childSnapshot.key;
    var eventdata = childSnapshot.val();

    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    document.body.appendChild(card);

    var cardtitle = document.createElement('p');
    cardtitle.innerHTML = eventdata;
    card.appendChild(cardtitle);  

   console.log(event);
   });
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you could use `cardtitle.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(eventdata)` instead of `cardtitle.innerHTML = eventdata;`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Saw this post which helped: [Display data from Firebase database in a HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684712/display-data-from-firebase-database-in-a-html-page)

This is what I changed:

```
// displays event listings on browse.html - modified 3/6/17
   events.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var eventkey = childSnapshot.key;
    var eventdata = childSnapshot.val();

    // listing data to be displayed
    var browsetitle = childSnapshot.val().title; // added this
    var browsecity = childSnapshot.val().city; // added this

    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    document.body.appendChild(card);

    var cardtitle = document.createElement('p');
    cardtitle.innerHTML = browsetitle + browsecity; // added this
    card.appendChild(cardtitle);  

   console.log(eventdata); // changed this to see what was going on
    });
 });
```